# iText 7.1.8 can't read some pdf file

Tags: c#, itext

when i open some PDF files,stuck in new PdfDocument(reader)

pdf file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AVda9qst-DiVbz4QFQh8iIv2aLn-uXRR

can someone help me fix it?

```cs
var reader = new PdfReader(file);
var doc = new PdfDocument(reader); // stuck
// some code
```

Comment: What is the error that you encounter?

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you don't write any codes to read the PDF file.  All you've done so far is declaring the variables.

Comment: It's just stuck in that line,no errors were thrown

Comment: It'll only load a PDF off the local file system.

Comment: I know, I just upload my file, if someone needs to test it,is local file system

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it on my environment because I don't have iText neither can I install it.  But check the link below and follow the example on the reading of the src:  https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-chapter-6

Comment: Testing at the moment as I already had a project ready for this. As you said, it is getting stuck when instantiating the PdfDocument.

Comment: I reduced the file to 1/4 the size (10mb), and set it off. It to 12 minutes to finally instantiate the document. I think the problem is that you're just reading a massive file.

Comment: I just test edit with iText 7 for Java, it took 81 seconds for the original document. Apparently there is a optimization need here...